# How can I write to Gradle logging while processing annotations?

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I have a `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` I'm using to generate source files. This is all working fine, but I want to write some debug messaging out to the console during build. I can use the annotation `Messeger` class, but this does not allow me to tap into the Gradle logging. What I'd like is to control the output by Gradle logging options, so `gradle -d ...` writes debug messages, `gradle -i ...` info messages etc.

Is there any way I can get hold of the Gradle logger from within my Java bean processing class?

I've read the [Gradle logging doco](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html), and have tried using SLF4J logging but this just writes my messages to stdout, which is picked up as `QUIET` by Gradle:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.gradle.example");

messeger.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "BeanProcessor: processing " + classElem);
log.debug("===debug=== BeanProcessor: processClass {}", classElem);
log.error("===error=== BeanProcessor: processClass {}", classElem);

21:28:22.211 [QUIET] [system.out] 21:28:22.208 [main] DEBUG com.example.beans.BeanProcessor - ===debug=== BeanProcessor: processClass com.example.beans.MyBean
21:28:22.212 [QUIET] [system.out] 21:28:22.212 [main] ERROR com.example.beans.BeanProcessor - ===error=== BeanProcessor: processClass com.example.beans.MyBean
21:28:22.216 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: BeanProcessor: processing com.example.beans.MyBean
```

Also, the logger I get is a `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` - the Gradle doco mentions: "*Logger ... extends the SLF4J Logger interface and adds a few Gradle specific methods*", so I would expect to see some Gradle specific logging class.

Gradle configuration is the as per [Annotation processor in Gradle outputs source files to build/classes making javadoc fail. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239243/annotation-processor-in-gradle-outputs-source-files-to-build-classes-making-java#answer-25242121)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A hack that could possibly help:

You could make a new custom gradle task that all compile tasks depend on and which sets a system environment variable based on whether -i, -d, etc. was passed to gradle (perhaps reading the value of [logging.captureStandardOutput](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) will do the trick).

Then read that environment variable in the startup of your annotation processor and use it to conditionally write to standard out.