# can't figure out the java annotation processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm trying to deal with annotation processors. I followed tutorials. Here is my code:

```java
@ExampleAnnotation
private void someMethod(){
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExampleAnnotation {

}
```

```java
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("org.example.ExampleAnnotation")
public class Processor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> anots, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        anots.forEach(System.out::println);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I created `META-INF/SERVICES/javax.annotation.processing.Processor`
and registered my processor: `org.example.Processor`. It seems like everything is OK, but block of code in the processor just dont start. I have no idea what is wrong. P.S.: I use Gradle and Java 11.

Comment: The content of the file should be the name of _your_ processor, not `javax.annotation.processing.Processor`. That should be the name of the file, but you already have that.

Comment: What tutorial? What do you expect? What do is actual happening? And how do you execute your code above to get the result you expect?

Comment: jmizv, all tutorials are almost same i tried this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder. result i excpect is to print every annotated method to system.out

Comment: Looking at that link, it seems you are at least missing the `@SupportedSourceVersion` annotation. Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: `System.out` doesn't always behave as you might expect, instead use the Messager class.

Comment: Mark, here is example: https://github.com/Blu3cr0ss/JAPIssue
@SupportedSourceVersion dont help

Comment: Colin, how should i use it? Its an interface

Comment: This question lacks too much information to be adequately answered. "It seems like everything is OK, but it isn't" — very poor problem statement. Have you tried running your processor with javac (e.g without Gradle)? Did you use `annotationProcessor` dependency to add it to one of your projects? What is the actual issue you are facing? Can you attach logs? Btw, using `System.out` does not guarantee that you will see output in Gradle console, at least use System.err for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29470860/1643723

Comment: user1643723, i edited my question, i think now its better.I also tried Messager(as Colin said) but its dont work too.also, can you tell me more about `annotationProcessor` in gradle?

Comment: By default java compiler runs all processors specified in the jar files on compilation classpath. This used to be very convenient. Unfortunately, Gradle developers, in their quest for faster incremental compilation, diverged from that behavior. When you build a project with Gradle, you need to specify all processors in special way: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies